# что вводить после LC_ALL в кавычках чтобы программа выводила хинди, а не (???????????)

Tags: c++

`setlocale(LC_ALL, "");cout << "उपयोग जारी रखने के लिए भुगतान राशि दर्ज करें";`
хочу вывести "उपयोग जारी रखने के लिए भुगतान राशि दर्ज करें", но выдаёт (???? ?????? ?????), собственно всё.

Comment: https://utf8everywhere.org

Comment: Попробуйте прописать в кавычках C (английская C, не русская). должно сработать.

Comment: `setlocale` здесь вообще ни к чему... Приводите кодировку файла и используемую консоль. И убедитесь, что шрифт в консоли поддерживает эти символы.